# How to resolve references to documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have an aggregate pipeline which returns the following set of documents:

```
[
  { "_id": 0, "refs": [1, 2] }, 
  { "_id": 1, "refs": [2, 3] }
]
```

How do I extend the aggregate pipeline to

1. collect the set of distinct values in `"refs"` (i.e. `[1, 2, 3]`) and
2. return the documents with `_id` matching the values in that set (i.e. 3 documents with `_id`  1, 2, and 3).

Comment: the expected output is  `[{ "_id": 1, "refs": [2, 3] }]` ? if you can add the expected output

Comment: @Takis The expected output is specified precisely in my question: the three documents with the IDs 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: if you wanted this `[{  "_id": 1},{"_id": 3},{"_id": 2}]` its simple to get
[playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6323209b78a49d87828514b1)

Comment: This is *not* what I want. See the accepted and upvoted answers.

Comment: its ok important is that you solved it, next time if you can add the expected output, i still dont understand and looks like the other people were updating to try to get what you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add 4 steps to your aggregation:

1. `$group` in order to collect all refs
2. `$reduce` with `$setUnion` in order to get the distinct values.
3. `$lookup` in order to get the docs from the `refs`
4. Format

```
  {$group: {_id: 0, refs: {$push: "$refs"}}},
  {$project: {
      refs: {$reduce: {
          input: "$refs",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$setUnion: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "refs",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "docs"
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$docs"},
  {$replaceRoot: {"newRoot": "$docs"}}
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/50qivKkglkD)

Comment: That's already almost what I want. The result of your pipeline is a single document with a property `docs` which is an array of the resulting documents. Is it also possible to get just the array of resulting documents?

Comment: Yes, just add: `{$unwind: "$docs"}`

Comment: I get the desired result by replacing the last `$project` stage by the `$unwind` and `$replaceWith` stages of @rickhg12hs's answer. And unlike the query in @rickhg12hs answer, this also works if some documents are missing the `refs` field.

Comment: @MoB. I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73719150/1409374) to what I think you wanted the input/output to be.

Comment: Yes, that's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.  Here's another way.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind": "$refs"},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "refs": {"$addToSet": "$refs"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "refs",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "docs"
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$docs"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$docs"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c7L99TgsyDk).

Comment: This also works great now. And the use of `$addToSet` may be more efficient than the `$reduce` with `$setUnion` from nimrod's answer?

Comment: @MoB.  Estimating efficiency of pipelines with `"$unwind"` and `"$group"` is highly data dependent, I think.  I suppose you would need to measure the execution times with your collection.